# Does MySQL support for BITMAP indexes?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Does MySQL support BITMAP indexes?  What's the syntax?

```
mysql> CREATE BITMAP INDEX ON tb1(num);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BITMA
P INDEX ON tb1(num)' at line 1
```

Comment: Did you look in [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html)?

Comment: Or do a basic search? The latter yields [this "worklog" about possibly implementing it at some point](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=1524).

Comment: You forgot to enable `WISHFUL_THINKING` your server configuration. This isn't supported. Please read the documentation whenever encountering problems like this.

Comment: If you would like to present the specific table and select; we might be able to suggest a good alternative.

Comment: Could someone suggest a similar database software to mysql that does support it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer - no, it doesn't. As of the today (MySQL 8.0), it contains only two types of indexes - HASH and BTREE.

Comment: Do you kown why mysql not support bitmap index？

Comment: Nobody implemented them yet?